# split string using Batch script

Tags: batch-file, split

You may call it a duplicate question but the fact is I could not find the solution. May be you can re direct if you do not want to answr.

I have a file name in a variable as A123_101234_3.
I want to split the string based on underscore as delimiter and then use the last part "3" of the string for further comparison ( it is actually month number).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Knowing it is the third element and elements are underscore separated, you can use the `for /f` tokenizer

```dos
set "input=A123_101234_3"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ("%input%") do set "output=%%a"
```

Knowing it is the last element in input but not knowing how many elements there are, you can convert the underscore to a space and iterate over the list of elements. This will overwrite the output variable keeping the last element

```dos
set "input=A123_101234_3"
for %%a in ("%input:_=" "%") do set "output=%%~a"
```

If the data includes spaces or other delimiters, you can replace the underscore with a backslash and handle the input as a file reference

```dos
set "input=A123_101234_3"
for %%a in ("%input:_=\%") do set "output=%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%# in ("A123_101234_3.csv") do set month=%%~n#
echo %month%
```

Comment: The solution is working perfectly fine. But instead of month number it is giving me 3.csv as the file name has the extension of .csv. I added a command,   if %month:~-5,1%==3 for comparison but here issue is what if month number has 2 digits. how can i resolve it? How can i just ignore last 4 character from it so that I am left with month number only for comparison? appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sharma: In your question you said: "I have a file name in a variable as A123_101234_3". If this is not true, but the file name have a .csv extension this way: "A123_101234_3.csv", then you should modify that information _in the original question_! Posting additional data in comments is a very bad practice, because you force the readers to read _all comments in all answers_ in order to understand your problem... **`:(`**